# PhantomJS not identifying CSS locators

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

Below UI locators works fine with chromedriver, but phantomJS is not able to locate them. Is this a limitation. Any insights or workaround is greatly appreciated.

```
 @FindBy(css="input[name='businessContact_firstName']")
 public static WebElement busiFrstName;

 @FindBy (css = "[data-test='container-business-contact'] [data-test='text-
        phonenumber']")
 public static WebElement busiPhoneNum;
```

Comment: You should add more tags, currently it's not clear in what language you're using PhantomJS.

Comment: @Vaviloff - using selenium webdriver with java bindings and phantomJS as a headless browser. This works fine with chromedriver

Comment: perhaps the problem is not with css selectors but incorrect timing so you actually not where you think you are on a page/site.

Comment: Good idea from Eugene S! Try making screenshots to check: if you're on the right page (could be redirected to mobile version) and if elements you're looking for are on the page already.